PeopleSoft Expression
I am trying to sum 2 expressions which are being used as fields in my report.
I have 2 expressions that I'm using as 2 fields in a report;
G.CALC_RSLT_VAL + G.CALC_ADJ_VAL - this is to calculate the Employee Pension contribution
(C.CALC_RSLT_VAL + C.CALC_ADJ_VAL)*-1 - this is to calculate the Salary Sacrifice Pension Contribution
I want to create a new column  to show only 1 value - individuals either have a value in one column or another.  Only a small number have a value under G.CALC_RSLT_VAL + G.CALC_ADJ_VAL - the field is blank for the majority.
I have tried to combine the expressions using the following but each time I run the report the column is blank;
(C.CALC_RSLT_VAL + C.CALC_ADJ_VAL)-1 + (G.CALC_RSLT_VAL + G.CALC_ADJ_VAL)
G.CALC_RSLT_VAL + G.CALC_ADJ_VAL + (C.CALC_RSLT_VAL + C.CALC_ADJ_VAL)-1
Any help would be appreciated
